# Implement paypal-rest-sdk in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, ecmascript-6, paypal-sandbox

Hello i want to implement Paypal payment into my Reactjs application. I tried the Node Module [paypal-rest-sdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK). everytime i want to execute my Function i get an Error. I's it even possible to implement the Paypal API into react? Is there a better way of implementing Paypal into my Application ?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { Button, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Redirect, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import paypal from 'paypal-rest-sdk';



const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/mieten",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Test Bagger",
                "sku": "001",
                "price": "150.00",
                "currency": "EUR",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "total": "150.00"
        },
        "description": "It's a test Payment"
    }]
  }




class  Payment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.paypalCheckOut = this.paypalCheckOut.bind(this);
  }


componentWillMount(){
  paypal.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
    'client_id': 'Afz_PUPqvABS-xCDgYJkuMxCo3samUfzrEynbHQZm7gPXf_2G36u1pPpBfu9q53uVt07KaH_2WYoj31K',
    'client_secret': 'EGH_JSn5Q-O2TDV9z2axR0fCicdLLSfHD81lsAkShMr_Z7ZUbgWrxg9n_WfKIquwMzZ920lHM2fIIHBE'
  })
}



paypalCheckOut (){

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, (error, payment) => {
  if (error) {
      throw error;
  } else {
    console.log("Create Payment Response");
      console.log(payment)
  }
});  
}


    render(){

    return(

      <div className="someform"
      <Button onClick={this.paypalCheckOut}>Checkout</Button>
    </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Payment;
```

this ist the Error i get:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid value for opts.mode
>       at new ./node_modules/stream-http/lib/request.js.module.exports (request.js:57)
>       at Object../node_modules/stream-http/index.js.http.request (index.js:35)
>       at Object../node_modules/https-browserify/index.js.https.request

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i added the error to the question ...